# Can I pass other components into Castle Windsor config?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Lets say I have a main component that I want to initialize in a specific way and I have it's constructor take an Interface for this purpose. Is there a way to define the implementation I want for this interface in my xml and in turn inject that into the main component as a parameter? Like this:

```
public interface IComponent2 {
    void DoStuff();
}

public class ConcreteCompImpl2 : IComponent2 {

    IComponent1 _comp;
    public ConcreteCompImpl2(IComponent1 comp) {
        _comp = comp;
    }

    public void DoStuff(){
        //do stuff
    }
}



<component id="component1" service="ABC.IComponent1, ABC" type="ABC.ConcreteCompImpl1, ABC" />
<component id="component2" service="ABC.IComponent2, ABC" type="ABC.ConcreteCompImpl2, ABC" >         
    <parameters>
       <component1>???</component1>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

Or am I thinking about this all wrong and there is a much simpler way to accomplish this? The main thing I want to be able to do is configure what 'kind' of IComponent1 will get injected whenever an IComponent2 is created. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one concrete class implementing `IComponent1`, then it will automatically be injected when you resolve `IComponent2`.

If you have several classes implementing `IComponent1` and want a specific one every time `IComponent2` is resolved, you need to specific an [inline dependency](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx#Explicit_service_dependencies:_DependencyOnComponent__2):

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IComponent2>()
             .ImplementedBy<Component2>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent<IComponent1, YourSpecialComponent1>())
);
```

I'm not completely sure you can specify this in the XML configuration, but honestly you should use the [Fluent API](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Fluent-Registration-API.ashx) instead of the [XML configuration](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Registration-Reference.ashx) unless you have a really compelling reason to use it.  As mentioned in the above link:

> Ability to register components in XML is mostly a leftover from early days of Windsor before Fluent Registration API was created. It is much less powerful than registration in code and many tasks can be only accomplished from code.